# Alert the page no. on jQuery dataTables page change event

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

The following is working for me:

```js
$('#datatable').on('page.dt', function() {
    alert("changed");
});
```

Whenever I am changing the page,the alert is shown.But if I want to alert the page no. which is clicked then what's the way

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`table.page.info()` returns the current pagination information. That is current `page`, number of `pages`, `recordsDisplay`, `recordsTotal` and more.

```js
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();

$('#datatable').on('page.dt', function() {
    var info = table.page.info();
    var page = info.page+1;
    alert('changed - page '+page+' out of '+info.pages+' is clicked');
});
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qpLtLfaz/**

Comment: I have some trouble with  page.dt. It happens so that it does execute alerts, but does not check checkboxes, at least not until I visit that page again.

Comment: @ivanacorovic, "_but does not check checkboxes_" (?) I dont quite follow you. Perhaps you could create a new question for this issue?

Comment: I already did, and solved it in the meantime, thanks.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561659/select-all-rows-while-using-pagination