# DataTable auto generated serial numbering not working properly.. for every pages

Tags: javascript, datatable

DataTable paging procedure not  showing continuous index numbers...! Now am showing 10 items per page, For the first page the Data-table serial numbering generates correctly from 1-10.. But every pages shows from 1 to 10 numbering, need to display continuous numbering from the second page, like 11,12... Am using the following code for Datatable.

Any help would be appreciable,

Thank you

```
<script>

            $(document).ready(function(){
                var t = $("#table_details").DataTable({

                    "pagingType" : "full_numbers",
                    "processing" : true,
                    "searching"  : true,
                    "serverSide" : true,
                    "ajax" :{"url" : "../dataTable/serversideContacts.php",
                             "type": "post",
                             "data": { "uid" :'.$uid.',"gid" :'.$group_id.',"sid" :'.$site_id.'},

                            },

                    "columnDefs": [ {"searchable": false,"orderable": false,"targets": [0,3,4]} ],
                    "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                    "language": {
              "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_"
                          }

                });

                t.on( "order.dt search.dt processing.dt", function (){ 

                    t.column(0,{ search:"applied", order:"applied" }).nodes().each( function (cell, i) 
                    {cell.innerHTML = i+1; });
                }).draw();
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: We really need more code if we are to see what you did wrong. This is unusable for a reproducable problem.

Comment: Sorry @MichaelDibbets....  kindly check now....

Answer (score 2):

Answer is based on the following: [Alert the page no. on jQuery dataTables page change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305749/alert-the-page-no-on-jquery-datatables-page-change-event)

(assuming `per page = 10`)

```
dTable.on( 'order.dt search.dt processing.dt page.dt', function () {
    dTable.column(1, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
        cell.innerHTML = i+1;
        var info = table.page.info();
        var page = info.page+1;             
        if (page >'1') { 
            hal = (page-1) *10;  // u can change this value of ur page
            cell.innerHTML = hal+i+1;
        } 
    } );
} ).draw();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can I {search:'applied', order:'applied'} un-apply search and order on this column.

Answer (score 0):

For DataTables >= 1.10.4,

```
"fnCreatedRow": function (row, data, index) {
                $('td', row).eq(0).html(index + 1);
            }
```

hope this will help :)